# Uso de constructores con y sin parámetros para generar un array de objetos

Tags: c#, array, poo, clase, constructor

Tengo que crear "n" cantidad de objetos con parámetros que serán definidos por el usuario. Al hacer el arreglo me causa un error ya que dentro de `AsignarNombre()` debo ingresar un valor del tipo que tengo definido en el constructor (en este caso de tipo int):

```
arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre() = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Sé que si pongo un valor numérico debería funcionar, pero como lo tengo dentro de un ciclo, necesito que ese valor sea distinto para cada objeto que se genere, así que no sé que valor o instrucción me hace falta para que haga lo que necesito.

También lo intenté de la siguiente manera:

```
arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Aunque tengo la sospecha de que no estoy llamando al constructor de la manera correcta, así que no me queda del todo claro.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Clase Estudiante**

```
namespace ClaseEstudiante
{
    class Estudiante
    {
        //Atributos privados
        private int Matricula;
        private string Nombre;

        //Constructor que no recibe parámetros.
        public Estudiante()
        {
            Matricula = 1234567;
            Nombre = "Joe Jonessy";
        }

        //Constructor que recibe parametros.
        public Estudiante(int matricula, string nombre)
        {
            this.Matricula = matricula;

            this.Nombre = nombre;
        }

        //Metodos
        public void AsignarMatricula(int matricula)
        {
            this.Matricula = matricula;
        }

        public void AsignarNombre(string nombre)
        {
            this.Nombre = nombre;
        }

        public string mostrarDatos() 
        {
            return "Matricula: " + this.Matricula + "\nNombre: " + this.Nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
namespace ClaseEstudiante
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cantidadEstudidantes;

            Console.WriteLine("-------------Captura de Estudiantes-------------\n");
            Console.Write("¿Cuántos estudiantes desea agregar?: ");
            cantidadEstudidantes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Array tipo Estudiante y su longitud "n"
            Estudiante[] arrayAlumnos = new Estudiante[cantidadEstudidantes];

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("--Captura de datos de los estudiantes--\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los datos solicitados: \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadEstudidantes; i++)
            {

                //Instancia del objeto tipo Estudiante
                arrayAlumnos[i] = new Estudiante();

                Console.WriteLine("-------------Estudiante #" + (i + 1) + "-------------\n");

                Console.Write("Matricula: ");
                arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarMatricula() = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Nombre: ");
                arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre() = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("--Alumnos capturados en el sistema--\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayAlumnos.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------Estudiante #" + (i + 1) + "-------------\n");
                Console.WriteLine(arrayAlumnos[i].mostrarDatos());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para salir . . .");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si asignar matricula es un metodo, entonces no le pasas un parametro poniendo igual.. te esta tirando un error (que aca no mostras) y es claro el error.. no podes asignarle a una funcion un valor.. si queres pasarle un valor a una funcion, lo pasas como a cualquier otra funcion....

Comment: Tu funcion `public void AsignarNombre(string nombre)` requiere un argumento de tipo `string`  en esta linea  `arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())); ` le estas pasando un parametro de tipo  `int ` eso generará un error en tiempo de diseño, espero que el compilador te lo esté indicando; ademas de que si lo que tecleo el usuario no es un número esta instrucción `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` generará un error entiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error se encuentra en el Main, en estas líneas:

```
            Console.Write("Matricula: ");
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarMatricula() = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Nombre: ");
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre() = Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Para solucionarlo, en primer lugar debes recordar que, tanto *AsignarMatricula* como *AsignarNombre* **son dos métodos a los que les debes pasar un argumento que actúe como parámetro.**

---

Recuerda que para pasar dichos argumentos, debes  introducir los valores **dentro del paréntesis**. Por lo cual, para arreglar tu problema, simplemente tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
            Console.Write("Matricula: ");
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarMatricula(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

            Console.Write("Nombre: ");
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre(Console.ReadLine());
```

---

Si esta solución aún te resulta algo liosa, puedes hacerlo por pasos: primero creas una variable, luego lees el valor que introduce el usuario y le asignas dicho input a la variable que has creado y, posteriormente, pasas la variable como argumento. Te dejo el código de ejemplo para que lo veas:

```
            Console.Write("Matricula: ");
            int matricula;
            matricula = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarMatricula(matricula);

            Console.Write("Nombre: ");
            string nombre;
            nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            arrayAlumnos[i].AsignarNombre(nombre);
```

---

Espero haberte ayudado, y si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar de nuevo! :)

Comment: Muchas gracias BlueByte, solucionó mi problema, la única pregunta que aún tengo la duda es ¿Mi constructor que recibe parámetros está trabajando?  ¿O solo está allí sin más? Es algo que no logro comprender. me expresaron un comentario en el que me decían que no estaba llamando los parámetros de mi constructor.

Comment: Por supuesto. Los constructores son métodos que se ejecutan cuando creas el objeto. En término simple, cada vez que creas un estudiante nuevo, estás llamando al constructor de dicho objeto. 
Inicialmente, tus estudiantes se generan a través del constructor que *NO RECIBE PARÁMETROS* y tienen por defecto el nombre de "Joe Jonessy" y de matrícula 1234567. Esto se debe a que, cuando creas a tus estudiantes `arrayAlumnos[i] = new Estudiante();` no le pasas ningún parámetro por lo cual tomarán los valores por defecto.

Comment: Si por ejemplo, crearas a tus estudiantes así: `arrayAlumnos[i] = new Estudiante(123, "Juan");` estarías pasando parámetros al constructor, por lo cual estarías llamando al constructor que toma parámetros.